# How to avoid creating blank notification popup without content

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, notifications, foregroundnotification

I have a service that creates ongoing notification as below. Only reason I need to create this notification is because I want to keep my service running when application is closed.

I don't wan't to display any content in notification. But every time this notification is created it shows blank popup to user which is annoying and it does not go away for long time. How can I avoid that ?

```
var _notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
   .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Mipmap.icon)
   .SetPriority((int)Android.App.NotificationPriority.Min)
   .SetOnlyAlertOnce(true)
   .SetOngoing(true);

var notification = _notificationBuilder.Build();
StartForeground(SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: this is not the way to create a background service

Comment: I can't use IntentService because my service suppose to keep running infinite time pulling data every minute and my application should be able to read data from Service whenever it lunched. This is the closest solution I found working but it needs foreground notification binded otherwise service gets destroyed. Can you refer me to proper way to make background service ?

Answer (score 0):

notificationBuilder is simply an object that creates a notification popup.

If you want to implement a way for users to dismiss notifications, apply that option.

```
SetOngoing (false)
```

If you want to add some text

```
setContentTitle(messageTitle)
setContentText(messageBody)
```

If you don't want to have any notifications at all, you can delete all the NotificationCompat code. It is not related to service.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android doc, when using Foreground Service, a non-dismissible notification for the status bar is a must, even if you try to hide the notification by setting min priority, it will replace it with default behavior. Please refer to ‘[Running a service in the foreground](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)’ for more information.

An everlasting service can take much system resource and slow down the device, so Android put restricts to avoid abuse, but it also provides several ways for [reasonabel background jobs](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work), one of them is [WorkManager](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-workmanager/)'s **PeriodicWorkRequest**, which can run with app closed, and can come back to live when conditions met, even when your device restart. But it has some restrictions like: max run time 10 mins, min repeat interval 15 mins.

To use WorkManager, you need to create your Worker class first, say CalculatorWorker, and then build the workrequet to run every 20 mins for it:

```
PeriodicWorkRequest taxWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder.From<CalculatorWorker>(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20)).Build();
```

Hand it to the system:

```
WorkManager.Instance.Enqueue(taxWorkRequest);
```